# Excel interop. Save xls as csv without losing the precision

Tags: c#, excel

I want to save a worksheet as CSV file using Excel interop. Doing so by using:

```
sheet.SaveAs(tempfile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows);
```

causes losing of precision. Iterating over each cell and constructing CSV is not an option as its very slow. Getting an array of values from Range is not good as well, as I cannot obtain NumberFormat of cells this way.

I noticed that precision is lost because during the export to CSV saved value is the one displayed, not the one actually being in the cell.

Any advice?

Comment: I usually work with values with 10 or more significant figures, and have never noticed any issue.  How much precision do you need?

Comment: Values up to 15 significant figures.

Comment: What if you just set the displayed format to 15 significant digits before saving?

Comment: you could also just read in all the data into a C# object[,] and write the CSV file in C# rather than asking excel to save.

Comment: Doug, how to do it in c#? Dan, the problem is to write to CSV I need to know the NumberFormat as it contains information whether cell contains number or %. I can't read NumberFormat without looking at every cell. It's too many rpc calls.